# Rails 4.1. Heroku ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric - character varying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

Here is my controller where I hit the query:

```
def search_by_location
  @stores = Store.includes(:images).near([params[:latitude], params[:longitude]], 10)
end
```

All works great on local machine. On PG, Heroku I get an error.

Here is the logs :

```
2016-06-23T08:04:56.392549+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/customer/search_by_location?type=daeal&page=1" host=loyelte.herokuapp.com request_id=0364888a-3866-4acd-bea0-17a4bf4eaeee fwd="122.162.251.21" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-06-23T08:04:56.362768+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/api/customer/search_by_location?type=daeal&page=1" for 122.162.251.21 at 2016-06-23 08:04:56 +0000
2016-06-23T08:04:56.365114+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Customer::CustomersController#search_by_location as */*
2016-06-23T08:04:56.365163+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"latitude"=>"28", "longitude"=>"77", "type"=>"daeal", "page"=>"1", "customer"=>{}}
2016-06-23T08:04:56.366751+00:00 app[web.1]:   Authentication Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "authentications".* FROM "authentications" WHERE "authentications"."auth_token" = $1 AND "authentications"."subject_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["auth_token", "41360d38bef547ab8e9ae2ce47459c53"], ["subject_type", "Customer"]]
2016-06-23T08:04:56.368775+00:00 app[web.1]:   Customer Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
2016-06-23T08:04:56.371919+00:00 app[web.1]:   Store Load (1.4ms)  SELECT stores.*, 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((28.0 - stores.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(28.0 * PI() / 180) * COS(stores.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((77.0 - stores.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) AS distance, MOD(CAST((ATAN2( ((stores.longitude - 77.0) / 57.2957795), ((stores.latitude - 28.0) / 57.2957795)) * 57.2957795) + 360 AS decimal), 360) AS bearing FROM "stores" WHERE (stores.latitude BETWEEN 27.85526821688915 AND 28.14473178311085 AND stores.longitude BETWEEN 76.83608111706583 AND 77.16391888293417 AND (3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((28.0 - stores.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(28.0 * PI() / 180) * COS(stores.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((77.0 - stores.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) BETWEEN 0.0 AND 10)  ORDER BY distance ASC
2016-06-23T08:04:56.372212+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)
2016-06-23T08:04:56.373468+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-23T08:04:56.373476+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric - character varying
2016-06-23T08:04:56.373477+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...*, 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((28.0 - stores.l...
2016-06-23T08:04:56.373477+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2016-06-23T08:04:56.373478+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
2016-06-23T08:04:56.373479+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT stores.*, 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((28.0 - stores.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(28.0 * PI() / 180) * COS(stores.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((77.0 - stores.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) AS distance, MOD(CAST((ATAN2( ((stores.longitude - 77.0) / 57.2957795), ((stores.latitude - 28.0) / 57.2957795)) * 57.2957795) + 360 AS decimal), 360) AS bearing FROM "stores" WHERE (stores.latitude BETWEEN 27.85526821688915 AND 28.14473178311085 AND stores.longitude BETWEEN 76.83608111706583 AND 77.16391888293417 AND (3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((28.0 - stores.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(28.0 * PI() / 180) * COS(stores.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((77.0 - stores.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) BETWEEN 0.0 AND 10)  ORDER BY distance ASC):
```

Comment: Were migrations run successfully on Heroku deploy after you've installed *geocoder* gem? Make sure your migrations set `latitude` and `longitude` fields on your `stores` table to `float`.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful reply.
when i changed `latitude` and `longitude` fields **datatype** to `float` after that it worked for me.

Comment: Let me add it as an answer for future googlers and extra +25 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our comments with OP, he is using `geocoder` gem. The table fields for `latitude` and `longitude` fields must be set to `float`.